# python - library to browse and download files from a remote server

Tags: python

Have a webserver that has some folder/file structure. This list keeps on changing. I can download using `requests` if I have the full path, but the list of files is dynamic; looking to find the more recent file based on timestamps.

I can scrape the HTML, but hoping to avoid. Looking for some sort of a "remote file browser, similar to `pathlib`"

Does anyone know if there is a library that would let me browse these remote files if I give it the root of the url?

TIA

Comment: if server has dynamic page which shows new files then you can use `requests` (or `urllib`) to get this page (as HTML) and `beautifulsoup` (or `lxml`) to search links to new files in this HTML, and use these links with `requests` again to get files. It is called "scraping"

Comment: HTTP doesn't provide any built-in way to browse files on a webserver. Servers can be configured to synthesize directory listings, but there's no standard format for it.

Comment: @furas Thank you. Forgot to mention, I am trying to avoid scraping html. Do you know if there's some library that can let me browse the files on a remote machine?

Comment: Requests for library recommendations are explicitly off-topic.

Comment: @Barmar I see "use requests" or "use serilog" recommendations on SO all the time. what do you mean? Is that some sort of a new rule on SO? Think I am not understanding what you mean.

Comment: It's not a new rule. See item #3 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You're not supposed to ask specifically for software recommendations. But that doesn't mean people can't offer suggestions if they think it would be a better solution than what you're doing.

Comment: Normally web servers don't have function to browse files on server. FIrst: because usually nobody need it - web server was invented to serve web pages with information. But some servers may have function to generate list of files on server but usually admins turn it off (see second reason). Second: because it can be used by hackers to get access to private files or source code of web pages - and this may gives information how to hack server. BTW: some servers may use `FTP` or `SSH` to gives access to files - but this needs login and password.

Comment: sigh. will write a simple api, think it's more suited for my use case here. Thank you @furas